# git doesn't push anything with no clear reason

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I've tried removing and installing git and VScode , I don't know what is the problem exactly

The problem started when I tried to push something while VS code is open

[image]

Comment: Please include the error details as text in the question: images are too hard to read

Answer (score 0):

Please don't attach images, they are pretty hard to read as said in the comments.

Your error is:

`fatal: Authentication failed for`

You are using invalid credentials or, if you can `git clone` and `git pull`, you don't have write permission in the target repository.